# Copy a DVD in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dvd, clone

Is there any built-in way of copying DVDs in Windows 7 or do I need to install a third party tool?

Comment: Are you talking movies/games or dvd's you created yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in tool to copy DVDs in Windows 7. You will need to install a third-party tool, such as [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr).

UPDATE: As mentioned by others, Handbrake is not *ideally suited* for DVD copying, but it will work. [DVDShrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org/) or [DVD Decrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/) (or numerous other newer DVD copying applications) will work as well. It stands, though, that this functionality is not built into Windows.

Comment: Handbrake doesn't really copy a DVD though, does it? I thought Handbrake was for compressing video...

Comment: Sure it does. It does not come with the DeCSS module (if I remember correctly) since the authors are being cautious due to DMCA in the U.S., but once that's added back in, it copies them fine. And non-encrypted DVDs can be copied without that module.

Comment: not a very explanatory answer.  see my comment because it deserves the green checkmark.

Comment: The last entry in DVDShrinks rev history is from 2004. The odds of it working in WIn7 seem very slim.

Comment: @jcollum DVDShrink works on Windows 7 according to [this](http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/744655) (though you may need to add the application to the list of DEP programs to exclude; see half-way down the list of messages).

Comment: @Michael: DVD Decrypter did the job on Win7 for me.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is DVD Shrink.  The current version is available at http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Rip-Other-Tools/DVD-Shrink.shtml

Comment: It has trojan/virus scanned by virustotal.com https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/eb2b029003e4b600a4204fc72d896195835b3337d32eabcaece481722cb5379a/analysis/

Answer (score 1):

My method is to use DVDDecrypter in "Single FILE mode" (no splitting) to aggregate the .VOB data into a single .VOB on my hard drive and then use [AVIDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)   to rip the video as a .AVI container with .mp3 audio and MPEG-4 video.